# Excel VBA - using variable in function range

Tags: vba, excel

I'm using a function to set a variable:

```
Dim LastMemRow As Integer
Dim FLAGFileNo As Integer
Dim MemNoRow As Integer

MemNoRow = WorksheetFunction.Match(FLAGFileNo, Workbooks(TalkRegTempFile).Worksheets("Setup Sheet").Range("A1", "A2000"), 0)
```

Which works fine, however I want to replace "A2000" with a variable LastMemRow (previously set by some earlier code) so that the Match only searches to the last used row in col A of the target worksheet. I've tried this:

```
MemNoRow = WorksheetFunction.Match(FLAGFileNo, Workbooks(TalkRegTempFile).Worksheets("Setup Sheet").Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(1, LastMemRow)), 0)
```

and although the FLAGFileNo and LastMemRow variables contain the expected values, MemNoRow is always 0.

Maybe I can't use Cells in this way in a worksheet function?
(Excel 2010)

Comment: What is the value of `LastMemRow` when your code executes?

Comment: BIRDS VIEW: Try this `Workbooks(TalkRegTempFile).Worksheets("Setup Sheet").Range(Cells(1, 1).address, Cells(1, LastMemRow).Address)`

Answer (score 2):

Rather than using `.Range(Cells(1,1), Cells(1, LastMemRow))` which may or may not be referencing the wrong worksheet, concatenate a string using LastMemRow in place of 2000.

```
MemNoRow = WorksheetFunction.Match(FLAGFileNo, Workbooks(TalkRegTempFile).Worksheets("Setup Sheet").Range("A1", "A" & LastMemRow), 0)
```

Comment: + 1 I had totally forgotten about `"A" & LastMemRow` :P

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
MemNoRow = WorksheetFunction.Match(FLAGFileNo, Workbooks(TalkRegTempFile).Worksheets("Setup Sheet").Range("A1", Cells(1, LastMemRow).AddressLocal), 0)
```

If the first code worked, this should too. Let me know.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone's interested, this works:

```
MemNoRow = WorksheetFunction.Match(FLAGFileNo, Workbooks(TalkRegTempFile).Worksheets("Setup   Sheet").Range("A1", "A" & CStr(LastMemRow)), 0)
```

i.e. instead of "A2000" in the original post use "A" & CStr(LastMemRow), the last bit converts the LastMemRow integer variable into a string.

Thanks for your replies, pointed me in the right direction.